# how to set value for the column grand total in fast report 4

Tags: fastreport

I have a DB Cross-tab object [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvfe.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvfe.jpg)

i whant set value for column grand total for exampel :
A+B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I = Grand ToTal

or 
Grand Total = Grand Total -A -B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use cross' OnPrintCell event (Grand Total = Grand Total - A):

```
procedure Cross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if ColumnIndex = 0 then
    if Value <> null then 
      Set('Var0', Value)
    else
      Set('Var0', 0);
  if Cross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then Memo.Text := VarToStr(Value - Get('Var0'));
end;
```

Comment: Hi dear gpi very very very tnx . you are my loveeeeee

Comment: dear gpi , hi , again very tnx. but  how to calc (Grand Total = Grand Total - A - B ) . How to write syntax?

Comment: procedure Cross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if ColumnIndex = 0 then
    if Value <> null then 
      Set('Var0', Value)
    else
      Set('Var0', 0);
if ColumnIndex = 1 then
    if Value <> null then 
      Set('Var1', Value)
    else
      Set('Var1', 0);
  if Cross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then Memo.Text := VarToStr(Value - Get('Var0') - Get('Var1'));
end;

Comment: hi again . if i want set condition for headers values no column Index . and value is string . and i have 2 value condition the 1th value is column[0] and   2th value is column[1]

Comment: How i can change format display Grand Total Column to numberic ?

Comment: `procedure Cross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
  if Cross1.IsGrandTotalColumn(ColumnIndex) then Memo.Text := FormatFloat('0.00', Value);                                                          
end;`